# How can we reach the information with the opensubtitles API?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take the first download 'str' zip link. I don't need more than one file of information. When I tried a not famous movie such as Shame 2011 My code worked but when I tried Avatar doesn't work. I think the code trying to take a lot of 'str' files information, API after that blocks this request.

**How I can reach the first English str file download link? **

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
from pprint import pprint

imdb='tt0499549'#-->Avatar
#'tt1723811'-->Shame 2011

server = ServerProxy("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc")
token = server.LogIn('yourusername', 'yourpassword', 'eng', 'TemporaryUserAgent')['token']
response = server.SearchSubtitles(token, [{'sublanguageid': 'eng', 'query':imdb }])#'moviehash':"0"
pprint(response)
```

You only have five attempts with TemporaryUserAgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out opensubtitle's new API - here's the [documentation](https://opensubtitles.stoplight.io/docs/opensubtitles-api/open_api.json/paths/%7E1api%7E1v1%7E1download/post).  It's way easier to use than the older API.

Grabbing subtitles is as easy as

```
    headers = {
        'Api-Key': api_key,
    }

    params = (
        ('imdb_id', movie_id),
    )

    response = requests.get('https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/subtitles', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Where api_key is your api_key from their website, and movie_id is the movie's IMDB id (e.g., Titanic's ID is 0120338, and can be found within the URL of its movie page on IMDb - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/)

An example of the response returned looks like this:

```
{'id': '5164746',
 'type': 'subtitle',
 'attributes': {'subtitle_id': '5164746',
  'language': 'en',
  'download_count': 9608,
  'new_download_count': 46,
  'hearing_impaired': False,
  'hd': True,
  'format': None,
  'fps': 23.976,
  'votes': 0,
  'points': 0,
  'ratings': 0.0,
  'from_trusted': False,
  'foreign_parts_only': False,
  'auto_translation': False,
  'ai_translated': False,
  'machine_translated': None,
  'upload_date': '2020-02-09T13:59:42Z',
  'release': '2160p.4K.BluRay.x265.10bit.AAC5.1-[YTS.MX]',
  'comments': "Slightly resynced the 1080p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.LT] version by explosiveskull to this 4K release. HI removed. I didn't do 4K sync for Infinity War, as they're already on site here:\r\nHi: https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/7436082/avengers-infinity-war-en\r\nNo HI: https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/7436058/avengers-infinity-war-en",
  'legacy_subtitle_id': 8092829,
  'uploader': {'uploader_id': 66694,
   'name': 'pooond',
   'rank': 'bronze member'},
  'feature_details': {'feature_id': 626618,
   'feature_type': 'Movie',
   'year': 2019,
   'title': 'Avengers: Endgame',
   'movie_name': '2019 - Avengers: Endgame',
   'imdb_id': 4154796,
   'tmdb_id': 299534},
  'url': 'https://www.opensubtitles.com/en/subtitles/legacy/8092829',
  'related_links': {'label': 'All subtitles for Avengers: Endgame',
   'url': 'https://www.opensubtitles.com/en/movies/2019-untitled-avengers-movie',
   'img_url': 'https://s9.osdb.link/features/8/1/6/626618.jpg'},
  'files': [{'file_id': 5274788,
    'cd_number': 1,
    'file_name': 'Avengers.Endgame.2019.2160p.4K.BluRay.x265.10bit.AAC5.1-[YTS.MX].srt'}]}}
```

To download a file you would take the 'file_id' and input it into a download request to the Open Subtitle API like this:

```
headers = {
    'Api-Key': api_key,
    'Authorization': auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"file_id":5274788}'

response = requests.post('https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/download', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Where auth is the authorization key you get from their API (/api/v1/login endpoint):

```
headers = {
   'Api-Key': api_key,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
    
data = '{"username":"__USERNAME","password":"__PASSWORD"}'

response = requests.post('https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/login', headers=headers, data=data)
```

and __USERNAME and __PASSWORD is your account's username and password.

Comment: I can't permission to vote your code but, appreciated Brian. In the first section, I just got <Response [200]>.  How did you get a response like that? Second; <Response [503]>  What did you write for Authorization. I have the API key and name.

Comment: Also updated the answer to reflect your latest comment ^^

Answer (score 1):

**There is a solution**

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/login"
headers = {'api-key':'YOUR API KEY', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
user = {'username': 'YOUR USERNAME', 'password': "YOUR USER PASSWORD"}

try:
    login_response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(user), headers=headers)
    login_response.raise_for_status()
    login_json_response = login_response.json()
    login_token = login_json_response['token']
except:
    print("Something wrong check again...")

imdb_id="tt0499549"

headers = {
        'Api-Key': 'YOUR API KEY',
    }
params = (
        ('imdb_id', imdb_id),
)
query_response = requests.get('https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/subtitles?', params=params, headers=headers)
query_json_response = query_response.json()
print("Report:",query_response)
#pprint(query_json_response)# All data here...

query_file_name = query_json_response['data'][0]['attributes']['files'][0]['file_name']
query_file_no = query_json_response['data'][0]['attributes']['files'][0]['file_id']
movie_img = query_json_response['data'][0]['attributes']['related_links']['img_url']
print ("Movie Image url:",movie_img)
print("File Number:",query_file_no)
print("Subtile File Name:",query_file_name)



download_url = "https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/download"
download_headers = {'api-key': 'YOUR API KEY',
                    'authorization':login_token,
                    'content-type': 'application/json'}
download_file_id = {'file_id': query_file_no}
download_response = requests.post(download_url, data=json.dumps(download_file_id), headers=download_headers)
download_json_response = download_response.json()
print("Report:",download_response)
print(download_json_response)

link=download_json_response['link']
saved_file_name = "subtitle.srt"
r = requests.get(link)
with open(saved_file_name, 'wb') as f:
 f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

For new readers, there's a new solution for retrieving subtitles based on the [Python OpenSubtitles.com API Wrapper](https://github.com/dusking/opensubtitles-com).

You can achieve this easily using the following code snippet:

```py
from opensubtitlescom import OpenSubtitles

# Initialize the OpenSubtitles client
subtitles = OpenSubtitles(MY_API_KEY, "MyApp v1.0.0")

# Log in (retrieve auth token)
subtitles.login(MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD)

# Search for subtitles
response = subtitles.search(imdb_id=IMDB_ID, languages="en")

# If you want to convert the response into python dict
response.to_dict()

# If you want to convert the first subtitle in the response into python dict
response.data[0].to_dict()

# Download the subtitle locally
local_srt_file = subtitles.download_and_save(response.data[0])
```

This code allows you to search for subtitles using the OpenSubtitles.com API Python Wrapper.

Make sure to replace MY_API_KEY, MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD, and IMDB_ID with your actual credentials and the IMDb ID of the movie or TV show you want subtitles for.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this repository.
You can find more information and updates at https://github.com/dusking/opensubtitles-com