# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'?

Tags: python, decode, encode

**How can I convert this data to save the subtitle?**

```
data={"tt0064621":
     {"title": "Name of movie - 1971",
      "subtitle": "b'1\\n00:00:40,916 --> 00:00:46,346\\n\\xe2\\x99\\xaa A"
                "\\B \\xe2\\x99\\xaa\\n\\n2\\n00:00:47,381 --> 00:00:50,174"
                "\\n\\xe2\\x99\\xaa It\\'s C \\xe2\\x99\\xaa\\n\\n3\\n00:00:50,175 -->'"}}

sub_create= data["tt0064621"]['subtitle']

saved_file_name = "subtitle.srt"
with open(saved_file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(sub_create) #sub_create.encode() Doesn't work
```

Comment: Your data is a string containing the Python code for a bytes literal; you could use `ast.literal_eval` to parse it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: `wb` is for writing binary data. If you want to write a string just use `w`

Comment: You should mention the line which causes the error, even so it is not that difficult to tell in this case.

Comment: The string that you're working with looks rather strange. *What is the overall problem you are trying to solve here?* What should the file look like after this process, exactly? Are you trying to produce a plain text file that you can open in Notepad and see something sensible, or are you writing something to meet a specific file format? What is ".srt"? There are many duplicate questions I could possibly point you at, but I cannot possibly choose one without knowing the actual, underlying problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The "what is .srt?" part is easy enough to answer - it's a file format for media subtitles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip

Comment: Okay, so judging from that documentation, it is a readable-text file that should be opened and written in text mode. OP, I would like to advise you to make sure you understand how text works in Python generally, how it is represented, and what "encoding" and "decoding" actually mean.

Comment: Thankyou @kaya3 thats worked.             --->import ast
sub_create= ast.literal_eval(data["tt0064621"]['subtitle'])

Comment: The presence of a "stringified bytestring" - `'b"abc'` or similar - usually indicates a programming error earlier in processing.  Are you able to share the original raw json?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I create this JSON with https://stackoverflow.com/a/66826066/15008043 this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what's in your `subtitle` field is Python code, you can just call `eval` on it.  Here's a version of your code updated to do that:

```
import ast

data={"tt0064621":
     {"title": "Name of movie - 1971",
      "subtitle": "b'1\\n00:00:40,916 --> 00:00:46,346\\n\\xe2\\x99\\xaa A"
                "\\B \\xe2\\x99\\xaa\\n\\n2\\n00:00:47,381 --> 00:00:50,174"
                "\\n\\xe2\\x99\\xaa It\\'s C \\xe2\\x99\\xaa\\n\\n3\\n00:00:50,175 -->'"}}

sub_create= ast.literal_eval(data["tt0064621"]['subtitle']) # <-- added call to

saved_file_name = "/tmp/subtitle.srt"
with open(saved_file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(sub_create) #sub_create.encode() Doesn't work
```

Resulting contents of '/tmp/subtitle.srt':

```
1
00:00:40,916 --> 00:00:46,346
♪ A\B ♪

2
00:00:47,381 --> 00:00:50,174
♪ It's C ♪

3
00:00:50,175 -->
```

This is a kinda strange thing to have to do, but if you can't change the format of your data, then this seems like a good way to go about the problem.  It would be better if you could change your data to not have Python code embedded in it (or something else that looks like a Python byte array constant).

UPDATE: Please heed @kaya3's warning about worrying about where this data might be coming from and so the risk of running a full `eval` on it, I've changed the code per their suggestion to use a safer alternative, `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Appreciate it 'CryptoFool'

Comment: Please use `ast.literal_eval` for this instead of `eval`. The data seems to be coming from an API which provides subtitles for movies, and that API presumably should not be trusted with the power to execute arbitrary Python code on anybody else's computer.

Comment: Yes my source from Opensubtitles REST API I transferred to my JSON file. When I was used original data 'f.write(subtitle.content)' This worked. When I take this data from my JSON file. I got this kind of error.